# Efficient way for Buffering polygons with a large dataset

Tags: r, polygon, buffer

I use artificial grid cells (Polygons) for Sub-Saharan Africa to do a sub-national study. I have many variables assigned to each grid cell. Now, I need to include information (development aid programs) from the surrounding grid cells as control variables. By now, I try it with this code and with the raster package. (gid stands for the cell id)

```
  for(entries in nrow(dataset)){
      current_cell <- dataset[entries,]
      current_cell_id <- current_cell$gid
      prio_cell <- cellsSSA[cellsSSA$gid == current_cell_id]
      prio_cell_buffer <- buffer(prio_cell,50000)
      neighbor_prio_gids <- cellsSSA$gid[prio_cell_buffer,]
      neighbor_data <- subset(dataset, is.element(gid,neighbor_prio_gids))
      dataset$neighbor_aid[entries] <- min(neighbor_data$AID)
    }
```

As I want to estimate the effect for many years, I got 85.000 grid cells and R runs now for 6 days. Any ideas to make this code more efficient or any other way to solve my problem? Is there a buffer function that is more efficient?

Comment: If your data is in a grid, perhaps you should be using rasters and not polygons. With rasters you can use a focal filter. It is not fast, but with only ~85000 cells, it should be a matter of hours, not days.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I know this question is a bit cheeky, but could you help me how to rewrite the code. I just want to include informations from the neighboring cells.Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The code snippet that you have is not really something that can be used for reproduction and testing. It requires an example dataset etc.